# Is there an equivalent global variable $_FILES for a GET form?

Tags: php, post, input, file-upload, get

I want to get an uploaded image file from my form and display it later but I'm using method "GET" for my form, I've looked around and can't seem to find anything about "GET" having a global variable equivalent to the "POST" $_FILES variable.

```
<?php
$name = $_FILES['myImage']['name'];
$size = $_FILES['myImage']['size'] / 1024;
$tmpName = $_FILES['myImage']['tmp_name'];
$dir = getcwd() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'images' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $name;


echo "<img src=images/$name alt='img'>";
move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $dir);
?>

<form action="" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="myImage" id=""><br>
<input type="text" name="myName"><br>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

No.

Browsers will not upload files in a GET request, so there is no data for PHP to make an equivalent from.